# After applying clearInterval to an interval why doesn't the interval work again when called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

My game is quite simply you are supposed to click on the start button and move your mouse along the track until you reach the end. At the end the timer stops and shows your score. My problem lies with the timer. The timer work perfectly fine the first time but when you click reset to play again it only calls the interval once. Why?

Link to my full code: http://www.codecademy.com/TictacTactic/codebits/AQBK4L/edit

Thank you in advance!

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
var clicked = false;
var score = 1000;
var timer = setInterval(function(){countDown()}, 250);

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#start').click(function() {
if(!clicked){
    clicked = true;
    countDown();
}
});

$("#lava").mouseover(function(){
if(clicked){
    stopTimer();
    score = 0;
    $("#points").html(score);
}
});

$("#end").mouseover(function(){
if(clicked){
    stopTimer();
    $("#points").html(score);
    clicked = false;
}
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
if(clicked || !clicked){
    clicked = false;
    score = 1000;
    $('#points').html(score);
}
});

});

function countDown() {
score = score - 1;
}

function stopTimer() {
clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: It's not working the first time either. `setInterval(countDown, 1000);`

Comment: Sorry that was an old code I had copied and pasted.

Comment: Oh. Well shouldn't you be starting the timer in the "start" click handler?

Comment: i modified my answer now that i understand this issue.

Comment: my change fires the countdown method but your code is not working work showing the score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code `var timer = setInterval(function(){countDown()}, 250);` is at the top and will be executed before the methods are even loaded.  Add at the end of the `ready()`, look at the bottom:

```
var clicked = false;
var score = 1000;
var timer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start').click(function() {

  if(!clicked){
    clicked = true;
    score = 1000;
    timer = setInterval(function(){countDown()}, 250);
    //countDown();
   }
  });

 $("#lava").mouseover(function(){
   if(clicked){
    stopTimer();
    score = 0;
    $("#points").html(score);
   }
 });

 $("#end").mouseover(function(){
   if(clicked){
    stopTimer();
    $("#points").html(score);
    clicked = false;
   }
});

 $('#reset').click(function() {
  if(clicked || !clicked){
    clicked = false;
    score = 1000;
    $('#points').html(score);
  }
});



});

function countDown() {
  score = score - 1;
  $('#points').html(score);
  }

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are saying. Could you give me an example of what it would look like move the code to the window.onload event? What's wrong with all my function being under ready()?

Comment: The whole code stopped working after I added it in the $document.ready

Comment: what do you mean the whole code, I added the above code and put this: `$('#points').html(score);` in the `countDown()` method and I see a countdown.

Comment: Yes but I want the countDown to only work when called by the click. Also both of the mouseover events stopped working too. The reset still works.

Comment: ok, so your real question is why isn't the click working right?  that isn't what your question states.

Comment: In my original code when you clicked on the start button the code worked exactly how I intended it too but when you hit reset to play again the interval only fired once. The problem was that the interval only fired once.

Comment: i modified click event again, it works for me, as long as you click end and then click start again it works.

Comment: You are the best McKeown! Thank you for your patience!